# Algorithm For Bitmap

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm creating a HSL gradient from raw pixel data, ignoring the hue how should I determine opacity based off of saturation & luminosity.

Also remember this is somewhat of an optical illusion, where the blue is in the image, it's actually becoming more transparent ( essentially there's a gradient with a blue rectangle below the gradient ).

```
            double saturation    =  pixel.x / image.width,
                   luminosity    = 1.0 - ( pixel.y / image.height );

            double alpha_channel = 255.0 * ( 1.0 - ( ( luminosity ) * ( saturation ) ) );

            // Luminosity Channel to fade from white to black.
            double luminosity_amount = 255.0 * ( luminosity );

            // Set the pixels    Red / Green / Blue   Alpha
            pixel.color = color( luminosity_amount , alpha_channel );
```

Outcome Version:

[image: img]

Correct Version:

[image: img].

It becomes less saturated towards the right-middle. Meaning the bitmaps opacity is greater there.

If anyone could come up with an algorithm that would correctly fade the alpha channel from saturation & luminosity that'd be amazing.

Also reason why I'm doing this is so I don't need to create 360 textures for 360 degrees of hue. So I'd rather just create the gradient and layer the gradient over the hue.

Comment: HSL has no relation to opacity.  Alpha is always a 4th, separate channel, whether RGBA or HSLA

Comment: Also you can produce any hue from a single texture by multiplying a white texture by the desired color.

Comment: To use alpha in this way, try writing out the linear equations for R, G, B in terms of R0, G0, B0 (the fully saturated color for the specified hue), substitute those into the alpha blend formula, and solve for A.

Comment: But I would still just apply the hue to a greyscale texture using multiplication.

Comment: Not sure but seems you misinterpret the correct image... For me alpha is not related to other values, you have vertical alpha component gradually going from 1 to 0 and independant horizontal saturation/luminosity grading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a grey scale bitmap with alpha that you can compose on top of any pure color.

Easily done.  Imagine that the color underneath is red, for example.  Then you can calculate the color you would want at every pixel.  There are multiple ways to do that, but your 'correct bitmap' looks like this way:

**TARGET = lum * ( WHITE * (1-sat) + RED * sat )**

**TARGET = WHITE * lum * (1-sat) + RED * lum * sat**

You want the RED component to be provided by transparency, and the WHITE component to be provided by the bitmap gray:

**TARGET = WHITE * gray_level/255 * alpha/255 + RED * (1-alpha/255)**

Looks like you got the alpha part right:

**1-alpha/255 = lum * sat**

**alpha = (1 - (lum * sat)) * 255**

BUT, you got the gray level wrong:

**gray_level/255 * alpha/255 = lum * (1-sat)**

**gray_level = 255 * (lum - (lum * sat)) / (1 - (lum * sat))**

Be careful about the instability in the division when lum*sat is very close to 1.

Comment: Looks like something's applying a gamma adjustment